# Sync Model layer with presentation after animation?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a gestureRecognizer with panning connected to a view. The panning moves the view and then when I release the finger I have an animation to move it back to where it began. This all works so far. The problem comes when I try to sync the model and presentation layers after the animation so it wouldn't go back to position before animation. When I add this new code the view first jumps up, then animates and then finally jumps back down. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Animation
var animation = CABasicAnimation()
animation.keyPath = "position.y"
animation.byValue = -panLength!
animation.duration = 1
self.view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "basic")    // Run animation

// Sync model to presentation layer so that view don't snap back to former position.
var currentPos = self.view.layer.position
currentPos.y -= panLength!
self.view.layer.position = currentPos // Sync model and pressentation layer.
```

[Screenshot of simulator http://www.zamzar.com/download.php?uid=1bb237dc1b54a7d79c5f52c38715ea-ddbfdec855bd14d6&targetID=12Sr3NF0Ch8sOBNQrQinrOM_ZDHIILMpt&fileID=p19b7q9rca4is3b31a4m2qgaof4.gif](http://www.zamzar.com/download.php?uid=1bb237dc1b54a7d79c5f52c38715ea-ddbfdec855bd14d6&targetID=12Sr3NF0Ch8sOBNQrQinrOM_ZDHIILMpt&fileID=p19b7q9rca4is3b31a4m2qgaof4.gif)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found use another way of setting up the animation:

```
            // Animation
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                var frame = self.view.layer.frame
                frame.origin.y -= self.panLength!
                self.view.layer.frame = frame

                }, completion: { finished in
                    println("Animation done!")
            })0
```